# Reverse engineering using EF in core 1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a Database in SQLServer 2016 and I'm trying to reverse engineer it in VS2015. Because I want the Models to be in their own class and Not directly in my MVC Project. I create a Core 1.0 Class Library project and I then followed the instructions here [Reverse Engineer](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html) however although the package manager suggested all installed without issue, when I look in the project.json file, under dependencies it red lines **"Micorsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": 1.0.0-preview2-final** it states that this reference **does not support framework .Net Standard,version = v1.6.** It works if I do the same in an MVC/Web Api based project, but not a class library. Any ideas how I can get this to work, it's part of my separation concern and tiering.

Comment: have you got any solution for your problem? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @M005 Yes, I did I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within the Solution I created a standard class library project setting the target framework to 4.6.1. (not .NetCore). See screen shot attached. you can see the references and the project type. I used the reverse engineering guide from my question to this project. Once in here I simple copied the classes that I wanted to my .Net Core Class Library project. This all worked fine.[image]